# Extracting one dictionary from a list of dictionaries (Python)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dicts like this:

```
[{'name': 'kabuto', 'id': 140},
 {'name': 'articuno', 'id': 144},
 {'name': 'nidorino', 'id': 33}]
```

I would like to ask my user...

```
input('Which pokemon do you choose? ')
```

...and then return/print the one dictionary where user input and name matches.

For example, if input is 'kabuto', then this is returned/printed:

```
'name': 'kabuto', 'id': 140
```

Is this possible/what is the best way to do this?

Comment: ```next(dictionary for dictionary in dicts if dictionary['name'] == 'kabuto')```

Comment: If no two dictionaries have the same `'name'` item (as the question implies), then you might want to structure your data differently, so that instead of having a list of dictionaries, you use the name as a dictionary key. The corresponding values could then either be dictionaries, or just the IDs, as required. The lookup is then a trivial matter of indexing the (outer) dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible use this way using filters:

```py
pokemons = [{'name': 'kabuto', 'id': 140},
            {'name': 'articuno', 'id': 144},
            {'name': 'nidorino', 'id': 33}]

pokemon = list(filter(lambda p : p['name'] == "kabuto", pokemons))[0]

print(pokemon)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop:

```py
for item in data:
    if item['name'] == 'kabuto':
        print(item)
        break
```

This outputs:

```py
{'name': 'kabuto', 'id': 140}
```